# Interactive grid column to display full content but read only

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Environment: Oracle APEX v5.1.2 / Oracle 12c

I have an interactive grid report by where I have one field that is a display only column but it actually returns an error message description that could be quite long. Since I would like to keep my IG report to one record per row, is there a means of being able to display the full contents of this field without allowing changes to the underlying column value in the database?

Some means of a tool tip or being able to drill into the field to view all info but read only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use that column 2 times in the select statemente,

- 1 with substr to show in the line
- 2 complete that you will show it on hover (this one is a hidden column)

For Interactive Grid, go to column > Identification > Type >  HTML Expression.

Then under Settings> HTML Expression add: `<span title="&COLUMN2.">&COLUMN1.</span>`

It will show everything when you hover the field.

Comment: FYI, updated your answer to use `&COLUMN.` for column type: HTML Expression.

Comment: In a classic report I have that solution using #COLUMN# instead of &COLUMN.

Answer (score 0):

Im on 18.2, and I havent used 5.1.2, but I would assume the features havent changed. Set the column to Textarea so that if you click on it you can have the full text, but then you need to disable it somehow. Just making it Read Only should probably be enough, if not, you can probably also disable it using javascript.