# Add read more/ View more functionality on Oracle APEX page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to add a Read more /See more functionality to a column in my APEX page so that I don't want to display all the text in column. I have explored but I didn't get many data sources, any idea how to achieve this. Once again this is on ORACLE APEX application.

Comment: A simple option would be a modal page. Have a column that is a link, maybe set it to display as "Read More", and have it be a link to a modal page where you pass through the ID of the row and then have a display only item there that is filled with whatever text you want to read.

Comment: Best option in my opinion https://stackoverflow.com/q/56334645/9225468

Comment: I have used jquery slideToggle() to hide/show read only data in a form with a dynamic action. Worked like a charm.